# Need help removing a user from a java web app

Tags: java

Hi I'm fairly new to java,and I'm working on a a web app for college.When a user logs in you can see his user name and profile, the problem is that i can see my name as a user and I'm able to follow my self, so id like to remove my name as a friend.Its controlled from this.Any help would be great thanks.

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model
{
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public String email;
  public String password;
  public String nationality;
  public String statusText;
  public int age;
  public Blob   profilePicture;



  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sourceUser")
  public List<Friendship> friendships = new ArrayList<Friendship>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "to")
  public List<Message> inbox = new ArrayList<Message>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "from")
  public List<Message> outbox = new ArrayList<Message>();


  public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String nationality, int age)
  {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.age = age;
  }



public static User findByEmail(String email)
  {
    return find("email", email).first();
  }


 public boolean checkPassword(String password)
  {
    return this.password.equals(password);
  }  



 public void befriend(User friend)
  {
    Friendship friendship = new Friendship(this, friend);
    friendships.add(friendship);
    friendship.save();

    save();
  }

 public void unfriend(User friend)
  {
    Friendship thisFriendship = null;

    for (Friendship friendship:friendships)
    {
      if (friendship.targetUser== friend)
      {
        thisFriendship = friendship;
      }



 }
    friendships.remove(thisFriendship);
    thisFriendship.delete();
    save();
  } 



 public void sendMessage (User to, String messageText)
  {
    Message message = new Message (this, messageText);
    outbox.add(message);
    to.inbox.add(message);
    message.save();
  }  

}
```

Comment: Is this Hibernate or JPA?  Do you want to prevent yourself from being your own friend, or do you just want to prevent yourself from being visible in the friends list?

Comment: When I'm logged in i can see all the members and there is an option to follow them and send messages, i just want to remove my self from that list and not be visible This is the Members controller index method:public static void index() 
{
List<User> users = User.findAll();
render(users);
}

Comment: Without knowing what else that code does, it could be dangerous to change it.  But you could modify that `index()` function to accept your name as a parameter, then loop through `users` after it's populated and remove yourself if you're there.

Comment: Am I missing the code for this index() method?

Comment: Members controller index method:package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import java.util.*;

import models.*;

public class Members extends Controller
{
  public static void index()
  {
    List<User> users = User.findAll();
    render(users); 
  }
  
  public static void follow(Long id)
  {
    User friend = User.findById(id);
    
    String userId = session.get("logged_in_userid");
    User me = User.findById(Long.parseLong(userId));
    
    me.befriend(friend);
    index();
  }
} ithink all i have to do is user.remove(someUser); or somthing like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unfriend yourself by calling the unfriend method and passing the object representing you (logged in User) to the method to remove yourself from the list.

I believe it is better to exclude yourself from the list. Wherever you generate that list, when you add your friends, add only those users who are friends with you and have different username than yours.